# всплывающие окна с проверкой

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по вопросу - у меня основной код выполняется на php, хочу сделать проверку на кнопки. На php само собой проверку сделаю, но хотелось бы, чтобы проверка была со всплывающим окном.

Вот **пример** банального удаления записей из таблицы.

```
if(isset($_POST['argys']) and (!empty($_POST['abs']))) 
    { 
            $Yabs=$_POST['abs'];
            $result=$dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `Oke`.`tovars` WHERE `tovars`.`id` = :id;");
            foreach ($Yabs as $id)
            {
               $result->execute(array(':id' => $id));
            }
    }
```

Код рабочий 100%, единственное подскажите как проверку связать с JS.

Comment: отправляешь запрос на севере, где выполняется твой скрипт, скрипт возвращает результат, успешно или нет, в ответе на запрос ты ловишь, успешно или нет, ну и выводишь то, что тебе нужно

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен AJAX. При нажатии на кнопку, например, инициализируете ajax запрос, где-то в этот момент у вас всплывает попап - результат выводите в нужном вам блоке.

```
$( "form" ).submit(function() { //измените на нужное вам событие
    $.ajax({ 
type: 'POST',
url: 'путь до вашего обработчика php',
data: { x: $('#input1').val(), y: $('.input2').val() },
success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data); 
    }
    });})
```

А на стороне php скрипта результат, просто, отдаете через echo. Можете добавить стилей.